# Failed to load module org.keycloak.keycloak-server-subsystem

Tags: java, single-sign-on, wildfly, keycloak

When starting Keycloak demo v3.2.1.Final downloaded from official site I am getting the following error:

```
22:56:46,404 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.1.Final
22:56:46,590 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
22:56:46,675 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) starting
22:56:47,309 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:131)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:356)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:299)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: WFLYCTL0083: Failed to load module org.keycloak.keycloak-server-subsystem
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.parseExtensions(ExtensionXml.java:155)
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml$DefaultExtensionHandler.parseExtensions(StandaloneXml.java:126)
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_4.readServerElement(StandaloneXml_4.java:218)
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_4.readElement(StandaloneXml_4.java:141)
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:103)
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:49)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:123)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: WFLYCTL0083: Failed to load module
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.parseExtensions(ExtensionXml.java:147)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: WFLYCTL0083: Failed to load module
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.loadModule(ExtensionXml.java:196)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.access$000(ExtensionXml.java:69)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml$1.call(ExtensionXml.java:127)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml$1.call(ExtensionXml.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.keycloak.keycloak-server-subsystem:main
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:223)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.loadModule(ExtensionXml.java:178)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to solve the problem I created a file called `layers.conf` inside the `keycloak-demo-3.2.1.Final/keycloak/modules` with one single line in it:

```
layers=keycloak
```

Comment: It would be useful if you could explain _why_ this solves the problem.

Comment: As far as I remember it enables keycloak subsystem on Wildfly, which means that all the keycloak classes couldn't be loaded since it's disabled by default.

Comment: This is indeed the solution, i'm wondering why it doesn't get copied over in the build process as it is included in the dist if you download it directly from Keycloak.

Comment: You solve your own problem and save others' time. Great job!

Comment: This is what SO about, isn't it :)

Comment: In newer keycloak versions, I had to create the `layers.conf` file in `keycloak-VERSION-SNAPSHOT/modules` directory, if this helps anyone

Comment: worth mentioning that this fix still applicable as for Keycloak 13